# INDEX MATCH returning #Value when there are matches

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have some troubles with my index match function in the table **tbl_attrib_ytd**. I am using array formula, `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER`, which works when I use the formula for sector allocation as shown below, I get the correct values.

`{=INDEX(tbl_ytd[Sector Allocation],MATCH([@[    Sector]],tbl_ytd[Description],0),tbl_ytd[Sector Allocation])}`

However, when I use the formula

`{=INDEX(tbl_ytd[Security Selection],MATCH([@[    Sector]],tbl_ytd[Description],0),tbl_ytd[Security Selection])}`

I get an error `#VALUE!`. If I omit using array formula I get a match in *some* cases but still value errors in others. The match lookup value is directly pasted from the table I am looking into, so there should be no discrepancy.

**tbl_attrib_ytd**

```
|     Sector                  | Sector      Allocation | Security      Selection |
|-----------------------------|:----------------------:|:-----------------------:|
| Canadian Equity             |          0.00%         |         #VALUE!         |
| Communication               |         -0.05%         |         #VALUE!         |
| Consumer Discretionary      |          0.13%         |         #VALUE!         |
| Consumer Staples            |          0.36%         |         #VALUE!         |
| Energy                      |         -0.08%         |         #VALUE!         |
| Equity Options /   Warrants |          0.00%         |         #VALUE!         |
| Financials                  |          0.21%         |         #VALUE!         |
| Health Care                 |          0.43%         |         #VALUE!         |
| Industrials                 |         -0.16%         |         #VALUE!         |
| Info Tech                   |         -0.53%         |         #VALUE!         |
| Japanese Equity             |          0.00%         |         #VALUE!         |
| Materials                   |         -0.02%         |         #VALUE!         |
| Real Estate                 |         -0.04%         |         #VALUE!         |
| Utilities                   |          0.07%         |         #VALUE!         |
| Open End                    |         -0.01%         |         #VALUE!         |
| Other                       |          0.14%         |         #VALUE!         |
| Unassigned                  |          0.00%         |         #VALUE!         |
```

**tbl_ytd**

```
    | Description                 | Level | Sector  Allocation | Security   Selection | Total Effect |
    |-----------------------------|:-----:|:------------------:|:--------------------:|:------------:|
    | Canadian Equity             |   2   |        0.00%       |         0.00%        |     0.00%    |
    | Communication               |   2   |       -0.05%       |        -0.01%        |    -0.07%    |
    | Consumer   Discretionary    |   2   |        0.13%       |        -0.74%        |    -1.09%    |
    | Consumer   Staples          |   2   |        0.36%       |        -0.02%        |    -0.31%    |
    | Energy                      |   2   |       -0.08%       |         0.10%        |    -0.01%    |
    | Equity Options   / Warrants |   2   |        0.00%       |         0.00%        |     0.00%    |
    | Financials                  |   2   |        0.21%       |        -0.37%        |    -0.27%    |
    | Health Care                 |   2   |        0.43%       |        -0.89%        |     0.36%    |
    | Industrials                 |   2   |       -0.16%       |        -0.11%        |    -0.40%    |
    | Info Tech                   |   2   |       -0.53%       |        -1.06%        |    -1.79%    |
    | Japanese   Equity           |   2   |        0.00%       |         0.00%        |     0.00%    |
    | Materials                   |   2   |       -0.02%       |         0.05%        |     0.01%    |
    | Real Estate                 |   2   |       -0.04%       |         0.02%        |    -0.03%    |
    | Utilities                   |   2   |        0.07%       |        -0.06%        |    -0.04%    |
    | Open End                    |   2   |       -0.01%       |         0.00%        |    -0.01%    |
    | Other                       |   2   |        0.14%       |         0.07%        |     0.04%    |
    | Unassigned                  |   2   |        0.00%       |         0.00%        |     0.00%    |
```

The the last table I pasted is the filtered version by level 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your formulas are wrong. The last argument to INDEX is a column **number**.

The first one should be (not array-entered):

```
=INDEX(tbl_ytd[Sector Allocation],MATCH([@[Sector]],tbl_ytd[Description],0),1)
```

or just:

```
=INDEX(tbl_ytd[Sector Allocation],MATCH([@[Sector]],tbl_ytd[Description],0))
```

and the second one should be similarly:

```
=INDEX(tbl_ytd[Security Selection],MATCH([@[Sector]],tbl_ytd[Description],0))
```